# Run SQL Server 2012 Integration Services Packages in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2012, backwards-compatibility, sql-server-data-tools

I have currently some issues with our new Developement Enviroment (Visual Studio 2015 with SQL Server Data Tools) running SSIS Packages based on SQL Server 2012 / VS 2012.

As far as I can see Visual Studio 2015 has no problems with opening SSIS solutions made for SQL Server 2012. I am also able to edit/deploy the solutions and the corresponding SSIS packages. But if I try to execute a package or package Task in the local Visual Studio enviroment i get the following Error:

```
Exception deserializing the package "The package failed to load due to error
0xC0011008 "Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information 
can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where
detailed error information can be stored.". This occurs when 
CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
```

After some research I found out, that this can occur because of a backwards compatibility problem. So if I set the TargetServerVersion property from SQL Server 2012 to 2016 I am able to execute the package in the local enviroment. But currently we are using SQL Server 2012 on server side, so this is no solution for me.

Can anyone tell me what to do do get SQL Server 2012 packages running in Visual Studio 2015? We do a lot of manual postprocessing in the local enviroment, so this is important to us.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx

Comment: Thank you, very informative Link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the package is running now. The error was caused by the SSIS Connectors "Microsoft Connectors v4.0 for Oracle and Teradata", which we used to transfer data to Oracle. We now replaced all affected transfer tasks with a Script Task based on Oracle BulkTransfer. Now we're able to locally run all Packages in VS 2015 and also deploy & run Packages in SQL Server 2012.

@Hadi: Thank you for the interesting link!